# How to fix this on Termux

Tags: termux

[Here's the error when im installing requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMfvk.png)

Traceback (most recent call last): File

When im installing requests it came out. (in the image)
Then when on another device, the same error occurs, I don't know what caused itThen when on another device, the same error occurs, I don't know what caused it.